# Why can't I do my SQL delete query do not work am deleting from multiple joined tables?

Tags: sql

```
$sql ="DELETE  FROM elimu_advance,elimu_astashahada,elimu_msingi,elimu_secondary,elimu_shahada,elimu_shahada_uzamili,maelezobinafsi,mahali_utokapo,matatizo,michezo_unayocheza,mkataba,mrithi,ujuzi_mwingine,walezi,wazazi,picha WHERE maelezobinafsi.Id=elimu_advance.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=elimu_msingi.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=elimu_astashahada.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=elimu_secondary.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=elimu_shahada.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=elimu_shahada_uzamili.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=mahali_utokapo.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=matatizo.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=michezo_unayocheza.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=mkataba.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=mrithi.Id  and maelezobinafsi.Id=ujuzi_mwingine.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=wazazi.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=walezi.Id and maelezobinafsi.Id=picha.Id and mkataba.Mkataba='KUJITOLEA' and maelezobinafsi.Id= ?";
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Most databases do not support deleting from multiple tables in one statement (well, without using triggers or cascading delete foreign key constraints).

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete from multiple tables, you should join on the condition, for example :

```
DELETE elimu_advance, elimu_astashahada
FROM elimu_advance
INNER JOIN T2 ON elimu_advance.key = elimu_astashahada.key
WHERE condition;
```

Please note that this example works on MySQL (might not work in some other SQL versions, please state if you use a different one)